# How to receive Texts from phones for your webserver, and use the content of the text

Tags: text, message

today I'm trying to find out how to get it so when a person texts a number (I want to get a number for my website)  But when they text it, the content of the text goes into my database.  But my issue is, where can I look to be able to receive text messages?  I know this is possible because facebook does it.  Any ideas?  I know this probably doesn't belong here but I am confused.

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to get a [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) number and use their [API](https://www.twilio.com/sms/api) to receive SMS.